# How to know that latexmk picks up my configuration file?

Tags: latexmk

I've put `.latexmkrc`  file into my working directory, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Is there a way to check that latexmk picks up my configuration file?

Comment: `strace` and `grep`ping for “open” (on stderr)

Comment: Could someone provide the complete definition of the file as an answer, step by step, for dummies like me?

Comment: You could run it with `-norc` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: That's the thing - I can't really see if it makes a difference, because there are hundreds of lines of output...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `latexmkrc` file is just [perl](http://www.perl.org/) code, so you can just put a `print` statement in it:

```perl
# .latexmkrc

print("Hello, world!  I'm a .latexmkrc\n");

# rest of .latexmkrc
```

For more about useful assignments to make, see the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/latexmk).

Comment: Works like a charm. I put  `print` statement first in my config, and it shows up as the first line in the output.

Comment: Does someone know why `print(__FILE__ . "\n");` returns `(eval 13)`?

Comment: @Hotschke because you're trying to have perl execute python code?

Comment: Why do you think this is python code? `__FILE__` is known to perl.

Comment: `str.str` is perl string concat not python (`str+str`).

Comment: @Hotschke you are right, of course.  I should have googled before making a snide remark *blush*.  I don't know why, then.

Comment: @Hotschke The [perl monks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=985545) have some wisdom to share on this subject.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Unfortunately, their wisdom does not help me.

Comment: @Hotschke Yes, it's not obvious to me either.  The issue, I think, is that the `.latexmkrc` file is run through perl's `eval` function, which may not know what file it is reading.  I will poke at this when I get a chance next.